# Configure P6Spy on Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, p6spy

I'd like to use P6Spy with Quarkus but am unable to configure it by following [generic instructions](https://p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#generic-instructions). Has anyone managed to get these two working together?

Comment: I have a question relative to this question. Can you help me?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74938286/config-p6spy-on-quarkus-log-result-sql

Comment: I have a question relative to this question. Can you help me?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74938286/config-p6spy-on-quarkus-log-result-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P6Spy is available on Maven. I was unable to get the latest version working so I'm using 1.3. Adapt the following procedure as per the actual driver you're using (in my case `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`).

1. Add P6Spy dependency to `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>p6spy</groupId>
  <artifactId>p6spy</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Create `src\main\resources\spy.properties` with the following content:

```
module.log=com.p6spy.engine.logging.P6LogFactory
realdriver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
deregisterdrivers=false
outagedetection=false
filter=false
autoflush   = true
excludecategories=info,debug,result,batch
logfile     = C:/temp/spy.log
reloadproperties=false
reloadpropertiesinterval=60
useprefix=false
appender=com.p6spy.engine.logging.appender.FileLogger
append=true
log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=p6spy - %m%n
log4j.logger.p6spy=INFO,STDOUT
```

3. Replace `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` with `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver`
4. SQL queries should now get logged to `logfile` (in my case C:\temp\spy.log)