# Config P6Spy on Quarkus log result sql

Tags: java, spring, logging, quarkus, p6spy

- I try config P6spy in my quarkus project successfully. But now I want
  it log result sql. How to P6spy log result sql? this is my code:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>p6spy</groupId>
    <artifactId>p6spy</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

- application.properties

  quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver
- spy.properties

  module.log=com.p6spy.engine.logging.P6LogFactory
  realdriver=org.postgresql.Driver
  deregisterdrivers=false
  outagedetection=false
  filter=false
  autoflush=true
  #excludecategories=info,debug,batch,statement,commit,rollback,outage
  logfile=quarkus.log
  reloadproperties=false
  reloadpropertiesinterval=60
  useprefix=false
  appender=com.p6spy.engine.logging.appender.FileLogger
  append=true
  log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
  log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
  log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=p6spy - %m%n
  log4j.logger.p6spy=INFO,STDOUT
  dateformat=yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a
- this is quarkus.log :

  2022-12-28 03:37:06 PM|45|0|statement|select customer0_.id as id1_5_, customer0_.CREATE_TIME as create_t2_5_, customer0_.CREATE_TIME_UNIX as create_t3_5_, customer0_.UPDATE_TIME as update_t4_5_, customer0_.UPDATE_TIME_UNIX as update_t5_5_, customer0_.business_registration_number as business6_5_, customer0_.company as company7_5_, customer0_.country as country8_5_, customer0_.currency as currency9_5_, customer0_.description as descrip10_5_, customer0_.email as email11_5_, customer0_.mobile as mobile12_5_, customer0_.name as name13_5_, customer0_.status as status14_5_, customer0_.telephone as telepho15_5_ from customer customer0_ where customer0_.email=? limit ?|select customer0_.id as id1_5_, customer0_.CREATE_TIME as create_t2_5_, customer0_.CREATE_TIME_UNIX as create_t3_5_, customer0_.UPDATE_TIME as update_t4_5_, customer0_.UPDATE_TIME_UNIX as update_t5_5_, customer0_.business_registration_number as business6_5_, customer0_.company as company7_5_, customer0_.country as country8_5_, customer0_.currency as currency9_5_, customer0_.description as descrip10_5_, customer0_.email as email11_5_, customer0_.mobile as mobile12_5_, customer0_.name as name13_5_, customer0_.status as status14_5_, customer0_.telephone as telepho15_5_ from customer customer0_ where customer0_.email='hoatest14@gmail.com' limit 1
  2022-12-28 03:37:06 PM|0|0|result|select customer0_.id as id1_5_, customer0_.CREATE_TIME as create_t2_5_, customer0_.CREATE_TIME_UNIX as create_t3_5_, customer0_.UPDATE_TIME as update_t4_5_, customer0_.UPDATE_TIME_UNIX as update_t5_5_, customer0_.business_registration_number as business6_5_, customer0_.company as company7_5_, customer0_.country as country8_5_, customer0_.currency as currency9_5_, customer0_.description as descrip10_5_, customer0_.email as email11_5_, customer0_.mobile as mobile12_5_, customer0_.name as name13_5_, customer0_.status as status14_5_, customer0_.telephone as telepho15_5_ from customer customer0_ where customer0_.email=? limit ?|select customer0_.id as id1_5_, customer0_.CREATE_TIME as create_t2_5_, customer0_.CREATE_TIME_UNIX as create_t3_5_, customer0_.UPDATE_TIME as update_t4_5_, customer0_.UPDATE_TIME_UNIX as update_t5_5_, customer0_.business_registration_number as business6_5_, customer0_.company as company7_5_, customer0_.country as country8_5_, customer0_.currency as currency9_5_, customer0_.description as descrip10_5_, customer0_.email as email11_5_, customer0_.mobile as mobile12_5_, customer0_.name as name13_5_, customer0_.status as status14_5_, customer0_.telephone as telepho15_5_ from customer customer0_ where customer0_.email='hoatest14@gmail.com' limit 1
  2022-12-28 03:37:06 PM|52|0|commit||

Expect: it show result log

```
{
    "createTime": "2022-09-27 08:27:42:705",
    "createTimeUnix": 1664292462705,
    "id": 3787,
    "updateTime": "2022-09-27 08:27:42:705",
    "updateTimeUnix": 1664292462705,
    "company": "IMIP",
    "country": "VietNam",
    "currency": "KRW",
    "description": "",
    "email": "hoatest14@gmail.com",
    "name": "Tong Thi Hoa 14",
    "status": "Active"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default p6spy does not log results - please read about [excludecategories parameter](https://p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configandusage.html#excludecategories) and [default values](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy/blob/master/src/main/assembly/individualFiles/spy.properties):

```
#list of categories to exclude: error, info, batch, debug, statement,
#commit, rollback, result and resultset are valid values
# (default is info,debug,result,resultset,batch)
#excludecategories=info,debug,result,resultset,batch
```

in your case I believe that should be something like:

```
excludecategories=info,debug,result,batch
```

FYI. The only author of `p6spy` has [abandoned project](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy/issues/541) - I do not see any reason to use `p6spy` in new projects, moreover [quarkus recommends to use opentracing](https://quarkus.io/guides/opentracing)

Comment: I tried use "excludecategories=info,debug,result,batch", but it doesnot show result. It only show sql.